# XSLT 1.0 how to produce an empty result and/or abort the transformation when a condition is true

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

how can i abort the xslt transformation, if HeaderInformation/InvoiceType = CreditNote?

XML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SALESINVOICE>
    <Interchange>
  <Recipient>1234</Recipient>
  <Sender>5678</Sender>
  <CreationDate>2019-01-11:09:16:43</CreationDate>
  <Test>No</Test>
  <Interchange_Control_Number>123584</Interchange_Control_Number>
  <HeaderInformation>
   <OrigInvoiceNumber>1</OrigInvoiceNumber>
   <InvoiceType>CreditNote</InvoiceType>
  </HeaderInformation>
 </Interchange>
</SALESINVOICE>
```

Best regards
Julian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by "abort":

You can use `<xsl:message>` like so:

```
<xsl:if test="HeaderInformation/InvoiceType='CreditNote'">
    <xsl:message terminate="yes"/>
</xsl:if>
```

This will terminate with an error.

If you just don't want an error, you could also do something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:if test="SALESINVOICE[not(Interchange/HeaderInformation/InvoiceType='CreditNote')]">
        <!-- Here goes your XSLT code -->
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

This will output an empty document if an `<InvoiceType>` with the value `CreditNote` is found.

Comment: Actually, I had to edit my answer – @michael-hor257k got the XPath test "more right" than me. Also, his way of doing it without `<xsl:if>` is probably more idiomatic XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way (out of many):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="SALESINVOICE[not(Interchange/HeaderInformation/InvoiceType='CreditNote')]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SALESINVOICE">
    <!-- instructions to process the invoice -->
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```